# android get number of camera issue - always return max 2

Tags: android, camera

I am developing an app which is using 3 cameras. I have a device which have 3 cameras but when i call `Camera.getNumberOfCameras()` it always return 2 instead of returning 3. I dont know where the problem is. Can any one let me know if I am missing something.

Permission in manifest

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

I found that it is showing 1 front and 1 back camera only. Please help

Comment: i think Camera.getNumberOfCameras() returns 0 to n-1 number,
  so in your case it is working fine.

Comment: No, getNumberOfCameras should return 3 and all these cameras should be accessed by using 0 1 2.

Comment: what you are saying?return 3 and accessed by using 0 1 2

Comment: If getNumberOfCameras() returns N, the valid id is 0 to N-1.

Comment: ok fine and do you give permission in manifest ?

Comment: try getCameraInfo() to find witch camera not detected

Comment: getcameraInfo take 2 param. one is camera id and It returns the information about a particular camera. If getNumberOfCameras() returns N, the valid id is 0 to N-1

Comment: I know that @Learner, try with id 0 and 1 and find which camera not detected

Comment: it is working with id 0 & 1. if i remove 1 camera it is still showing 2 camera id 0 & 1 no matter which one camera i am removing.

Comment: @Learner : What device are you trying this with?

Comment: android TV in which camera can be added & removed easily